# Creating an array from an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes.

> rabbits = [{:color=>"blue", :height=>5, :name=>"Charles"}, {:color=>"red", :height=>12, :name=>"Henry"}, {:color=>"green", :height=>7, :name=>"Francis"}, {:color=>"purple", :height=>3, :name=>"William"}]

How would one create an array from this array of just the :height?

I tried: `rabbits.map(&:height)` and `rabbits.map{|i| i.height}` but neither worked.

Goal is to have `height_array = [5, 12, 7, 3]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work

```
rabbits.map{|c| c[:height] }
```

The other two methods that you tried expect `height` to be a method on `c` which is not the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried that but was not storing it as a new array. So when I tried to print cats on the next line it was giving me the original. Thanks again.

Comment: To rewrite the original array use `cat.map! ...` (note the exclamations mark). But I'd save it to another variable, `ages = cats.map ...`

Comment: Thanks Sergio. I did not know about that. Answer accepted. :)

Comment: I was asked to edit the question because it was part of a coding challenge and the curator was worried future students would be able to find this and use it for their answer. `cats.map` should equal `rabbits.map`  and `cats_age`  should equal `height` . Sorry for this inconvenience. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
rabbits.inject([]) {|height,hash| height << hash[:height]}
```

Comment: Seems to me that using `inject` is an overkill here :)

Comment: indeed it is but just listed down as an option

Comment: @AshishSaihgal I was asked to edit the question because it was part of a coding challenge and the curator was worried future students would be able to find this and use it for their answer. `cats.inject` should equal `rabbits.inject`  and `cats_age`  should equal `height` . Sorry for this inconvenience. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = cats.collect{|c| c[:cats_age] }
```

Comment: That's an alias for `map`, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Salil  I was asked to edit the question because it was part of a coding challenge and the curator was worried future students would be able to find this and use it for their answer. `cats.collect` should equal `rabbits.collect`  and `cats_age`  should equal `height` . Sorry for this inconvenience. :(